# A weird place of my iframe in my codeplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a problem with my iframe. On the top there is a bar, and on the left I have a textarea for putting in HTML. I also have two textarea's for putting in CSS and JS but they have `display:none`. Then I want on the left an iframe where I can see the result of everything I had put in. But the iframe is everything beneath the textarea for HTML. I have tried to change the positioning of my iframe but when I make my window bigger it is in a total other place. I am going to show all my code because it's possible that I made a mistake somewhere else.

```js
<script>
    var height=$(window).height()-40;
    $(".codecontainer").height(height+"px");
 </script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CodePlayer</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jqueryui.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  * {
      font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light",
  "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
  }
     
  body, html {
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
  }
  #container {
      height:100%;
  }
     
   #titlebar {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
    height:40px;
   }

   #title {
    padding:10px 0 0 20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
   }

   #menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:220px;
    padding:5px;
   }
   
  #menu ul {
    border:1px solid grey;
    border-radius:5px;
    height:30px;
   }

   #menu li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    border-right:1px solid grey;
    height:20px;
    padding:5px 10px;
   }

   #menu li:hover {
    background-color:grey;
   }

   #result{
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    left: 153px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
   }

   #runButton{
    float: right;
    position: relative;

   }

   #run{
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }

   #run:hover{
     background-color:grey;
   }

   .break {
    clear:both;
   }

   .codecontainer{
    width:49%;
     float:left;  
    position:relative;
    top: -24px;
    height: 100%;
   }

   .codecontainer textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:none;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    font-family: monotype;
    font-size: 120%;
    padding:4px;
   }

   .codeLabel{
    border:1px grey solid;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
   }

   #cssContainer, #jsContainer{
    display: none;
   }

   iframe{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
   }

  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="titlebar">
   <div id="title">
       CodePlayer
   </div>
      
   <div id="runButton">
      
       <button id="run">Run</button>
      
   </div>
      
   <div id="menu">
       <ul>
       <li>HTML</li>
       <li>CSS</li>
       <li>JS</li>
       <li style="border:none" id="result">Result</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
      
      
      
  </div>
      
  <div class="break"></div>
      
  <div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer">

   <span class="codeLabel">HTML</span>

   <textarea>Example code</textarea>

  <div class="codecontainer" id="cssContainer">

   <span class="codeLabel">CSS</span>

   <textarea>Example code</textarea>
      
  </div>

  <div class="codecontainer" id="jsContainer">

   <span class="codeLabel">JS</span>

   <textarea>Example code</textarea>
      
  </div>

  <div class="codecontainer" id="resultContainer">

   <span class="codeLabel">Result</span>

   <iframe></iframe>
      
  </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please tell us what you really to achieve ? your question is not much clear.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I want that my iframe is also the half of the window and next to the textarea for put in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in your html tags , your first `codecontainer` :

```
<div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer">
```

is not closed right after the below content so it's wrapping all other div's inside it by making them their child div's

```
<span class="codeLabel">HTML</span>
<textarea>Example code</textarea>
```

so it should be like this:

```
<div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer">

            <span class="codeLabel">HTML</span>

            <textarea>Example code</textarea>
</div> <--- you have missed this closing tag for first "codecontainer"
```

use this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CodePlayer</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jqueryui.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        * {
                 font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light",
        "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
                 margin:0;
                 padding:0;
        }

        body, html {
                 height:100%;
                 width:100%;
        }
        #container {
                 height:100%;
        }

         #titlebar {
             width:100%;
             background-color:#EEEEEE;
             border-bottom:1px solid grey;
             height:40px;
         }

         #title {
             padding:10px 0 0 20px;
             font-weight:bold;
             float:left;
         }

         #menu {
             margin:0 auto;
             width:220px;
             padding:5px;
         }

        #menu ul {
             border:1px solid grey;
             border-radius:5px;
             height:30px;
         }

         #menu li {
             float:left;
             list-style:none;
             border-right:1px solid grey;
             height:20px;
             padding:5px 10px;
         }

         #menu li:hover {
             background-color:grey;
         }

         #result{
            position: relative;
            top: -30px;
            left: 153px;
            border-right: 1px solid white;
         }

         #runButton{
            float: right;
            position: relative;

         }

         #run{
            padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
            border:none;
            border-radius: 10px;
         }

         #run:hover{
             background-color:grey;
         }

         .break {
            clear:both;
         }

         .codecontainer{
             width:49%;
             float:left;        
             position:relative;
             top: -24px;
             height: 100%;
         }

         .codecontainer textarea{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border:none;
            border-right: 1px solid grey;
            font-family: monotype;
            font-size: 120%;
            padding:4px;
         }

         .codeLabel{
            border:1px grey solid;
            width: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            right: 10px;
            padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
         }

         #cssContainer, #jsContainer{
            display: none;
         }

         iframe{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            float: left;
         }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="titlebar">
            <div id="title">
                     CodePlayer
            </div>

            <div id="runButton">

                     <button id="run">Run</button>

            </div>

            <div id="menu">
                     <ul>
                         <li>HTML</li>
                         <li>CSS</li>
                         <li>JS</li>
                         <li style="border:none" id="result">Result</li>
                     </ul>
            </div>



        </div>

        <div class="break"></div>

        <div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer">

            <span class="codeLabel">HTML</span>

            <textarea>Example code</textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="codecontainer" id="cssContainer">

            <span class="codeLabel">CSS</span>

            <textarea>Example code</textarea>

        </div>

        <div class="codecontainer" id="jsContainer">

            <span class="codeLabel">JS</span>

            <textarea>Example code</textarea>

        </div>

        <div class="codecontainer" id="resultContainer">

            <span class="codeLabel">Result</span>

            <iframe></iframe>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Arsh. If the world only exist off persons like you the world must be a very good place to live. Thanks for everything you do.

Comment: @RVDE always pleasure to help :) . glad it helped